# Set value on readonly input field Contact Form 7 WordPress

Tags: wordpress, readonly, contact-form-7, input-field

I have a readonly input field in my contact form created using contact form 7. I need to set the page title (`<?php the_title() ?>`) as the value on that readonly input.

My readonly input as follows.

`[text* selected-package readonly id:selectedPackage class:form-control placeholder akismet:author "Package"]`

I tried using `_post_title` but it only adding the value attribute to the input field, but it is not showing the value.

How can I add value attribute to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check word press plugin,

[Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/)

in which you can set,

```
Auto-filling a Post ID, title, or slug
```

set below code into your contact form 7 in admin:

```
[dynamictext dynamicname "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"]
```

You can use custom Js code by make field read only for dynamic field as well.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution is working and use **readonly** inside the shortcode like this [dynamictext dynamicname **readonly** "CF7_get_post_var key='title'"] to make the text field uneditable. Also don't change the word **dynamictext** which is inside the shortcode. You can change **dynamicname** to whatever you want.